# What does the Dikduk Hataamim of Ben Asher (the A. Dotan edition) say in reguard to the 10 sons of Haman?

Tags: product-recommendation, megillat-esther

After the ensuing back and forth on [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104137/does-anyone-have-access-to-a-keter-yerushalayim-jerusalem-crown-tanach) post regarding the authenticity of the small שׁ ,ת, and ז and the large ו by the ten sons of Haman, I would like to consult the [A. Dotan edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=sSoSAQAAIAAJ&source=gbs_book_other_versions) of Ben Asher's דקדוקי הטעמים. It is apparently more accurate than the [Baer and Strack edition](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38509&st=%D7%92%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9F&pgnum=1&hilite=fc647895-9183-4069-857c-6656146e6924).

What does Aron Dotan say in regard to these small/large letters?

Comment: Welcome Big Mouth! Is this what you're looking for? https://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D.html?id=sSoSAQAAIAAJ

Comment: @alicht yes that's it

Comment: @DoubleAA Do we know what manuscripts were used either in the old or in the new edition?

Comment: @Kazibácsi I don't, though surely someone does. I've never actually read Dotan's work. It's out of print and very hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/104143/1499), Dotan does not include this pericope in his edition.

Here is an concordance of the Dotan and Baer-Strack edition. Notice that Baer-Strack section 61 is not included.

[image: Dotan concorance]

This is what he writes about the manuscripts in the English summary:

[image: Preface]
[image: Preface 2]

Comment: So dotan believes that segment was added by someone else I presume...

Comment: @BigMouth See what I have uploaded.

Comment: Interesting stuff. So there's now way to definitively attribute our version of the letter to the mesorah

Comment: @BigMouth I am not aware of any evidence to prove if he followed that tradition or not. 
My hunch is that there were no small or large letters in Esther, since the Aleppo codex seems very conservative with large and small letters, but I cannot prove it of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94963/discussion-between-argon-and-big-mouth).